# GCDAsyncsocket write works but server not responds on background

Tags: objective-c, sockets, networking, gcdasyncsocket

I have a couple of apps that talk to each other through GCDAsynsockets

The problem I'm facing is that if the app is that if the server app is in background, it doesn't write back to the client app until it gets back on foreground

So the readtimeout of client waiting for the response fires the timeout.. but after this timeout, the server may get the data and return the response

so my question is, is there a way to cancel the write if I get the timeout (so I don't send it again) or is there a way to prevent that background issue?

I think it can happen in poor networks too, if the socket stays on router for so long or things like that..

thank you so much

Comment: Why do you "send it again" when you get timeout on client ?

Comment: Since if i get a timeout i supose the server hasn't received it, hence it doesn't answer, but sometimes it receives it after the timeout.. Thats the problem..

Comment: You're using TCP which will re-send the data which is lost, so you don't need to "send it again" by yourself. If the server is a app runs on iOS, when the app enter suspended state, it can't work at all, so it won't response to any message, but the message from client is received by TCP which is in control of system, the message is keeping in tcp's receive buffer, when the app enter foreground and call 'read' method, it will get the data from receive buffer. Furthermore when the screen is locked, iOS will disconnect the connection.

Comment: This is somehow something that is happening to me, The packets arrive sometimes 5 minutes after, so if I don't set a timeout, after those 5 minutes I get the response (it happens once, twice or three times a day in a full day working app) So i don't really know how to handle it. The app is a POS / KDS so if the order doesn't get to the KDS the food is not cooked :P

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what POS/KDS is... Timeout won't solve any problems. Though you re-send the packet to the server, it won't response either if it is in background. If you use app in iOS as the server, you'll face this problem.